# Cloudflare Workers: Inject code if URL includes parameter

Tags: javascript, serverless, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to inject some code with Cloudflare Workers if the URL includes the parameter `?beta`.

This is what I tried:

```
addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        handleRequest(event.request).catch(
            (err) => new Response(err.stack, { status: 500 })
        )
    );
});

class ElementHandler {
    element(element) {
        element.append(`<style>.test {display:none}</style>`, { html: true });
    }
}

async function handleRequest(request) {

    const url = new URL(request.url)
    const res = await fetch(request)

    if (url.pathname.includes("?beta")) {
        return new HTMLRewriter().on("head", new ElementHandler()).transform(res)
    }
    else {
        return fetch(request)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work... the code is not added to the head if I add ?beta to the Worker's URL.

I don't get any errors from the console. Could anyone spot what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem his here:

```
if (url.pathname.includes("?beta")) {
```

`url.pathname` contains only the path part of the URL. However, the `?` and everything after it is not considered part of the path. Instead, it is part of `url.search`. So you could do:

```
if (url.search.includes("?beta")) {
```

But this could break when there are multiple params, like `?foo=bar&beta`. Instead, the best is to use `url.searchParams`, which is a key/value map of all the params:

```
if (url.searchParams.has("beta")) {
```